# Guessing game is not letting while loops work

Tags: python

Trying to code a guessing game using while loops. The first few times I ran I was able to keep on guessing without the game ending when there's a limiter in the program.  However when I tried again later I'm not able to guess after one guess; it just prints "out of guesses".  Somebody else was able to run the same code fine and have the game end after three guesses like it's supposed to.

```
secret_word = "money"
guess = input("Enter guess: ") # check important
guess_count = 0     # starting number and then increases
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses): # two ways loop ends
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True # when they are out of guesses with the guess limit guess_count >= guess_limit

if out_of_guesses:  # confused about this
    print("Out of guesses")
else:
    print("Smart pants!!")
```

Comment: What do you need? That we explain your code?

Comment: You are looping over the same input three times. You want to put the `input` call inside the `while` loop to get a new guess from the user. This is almost certainly a duplicate of hundreds of similar questions; please search before asking, and spend a bit of time on learning how to debug simple programs. For a start, add `print` statements to see the values of your variables, or run the thing under a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: `guess` doesn't change.

Comment: If you are trying to re-run your game without ending the program just add the line ```guess_count = 0```at the last line of your code after the ```else``` also I see that you are not letting user input once inside loop. It will simply execute three times without you even noticing the problem, make it stop for user to enter guess ```guess = input("Enter guess: ")``` add this to your ```while```

Comment: @tripleee problem is that I did that and it did not work.  I put input in the while loop and it didn't work the first time. So I put it outside of the while loop. Now that I fixed it again with it outside the while loop it's working. It's so confusing. I searched a lot on google trust me.   Sometimes you just need someone else to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
secret_word = "money"
guess = ''
guess_count = 0     # starting number and then increases
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses): # two ways loop ends
    guess = input("\nEnter guess: ") # check important
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True # when they are out of guesses with the guess limit guess_count >= guess_limit

if out_of_guesses:  # confused about this
    print("Out of guesses")
else:
    print("Smart pants!!")
```

you just need to take `input()` inside `while`